# Test project in VS2010: wrong directory

Tags: visual-studio-2010, automated-tests

I've added the test project into my solution. I want my test to load the xml file that is placed into the test project. To find it I use Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() but it returns the testresults/out folder where there is not my xml file although it has in properties "Copy to output directory". I think in this context the output directory is something different from the moment when I'm running my test.

But how to provide the proper copying this file into the testresults/out ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Thanks everyone but I've just solved the problem. I need to add this file into list of deployed files in the Deployment section of test project settings (don't forget to click the "Enable deployment" check box).
Then you don't need any attributes nor directories. Just open your file (pure name without any directories) and viola.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the "out" directory for the build system is distinct from the "out" directory for your test results.  Use Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location to get the path to your code.  Path.GetDirectoryName on that helps you find the directory that the build system copied you .xml file to.